# How do I set a readonly field in an initialize method that gets called from the constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, readonly

I'm sure I've seen somewhere that I can do the following by using an attribute above my Init() method, that tells the compiler that the Init() method must only be called from the constructor, thus allowing the readonly field to be set. I forgot what the attribute is called though, and I can't seem to find it on google.

```
public class Class
{
    private readonly int readonlyField;

    public Class()
    {
        Init();
    }

    // Attribute here that tells the compiler that this method must be called only from a constructor
    private void Init()
    {
        readonlyField = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728447/how-do-i-set-a-readonly-field-in-an-initialize-method-that-gets-called-from-the-c/3728477#3728477) is the way to do it, in my book. If you need to initialize multiple fields you can do it using `out` parameters:

```
public class Class
{
    private readonly int readonlyField1;
    private readonly int readonlyField2;

    public Class()
    {
        Init(out readonlyField1, out readonlyField2);
    }

    protected virtual void Init(out int field1, out int field2)
    {
        field1 = 1;
        field2 = 2;
    }
}
```

Personally I find this makes sense in certain scenarios, such as when you want your fields to be `readonly` but you *also* want to be able to set them differently in a derived class (without having to chain a ton of parameters through some `protected` constructor). But maybe that's just me.

Comment: @Chuck: Hey, I never said it was pretty.

Comment: @Derar: Damn, dude... I think reflection is definitely *not* the way to go about this. Why use reflection on your own class, when all the code is right in front of you?

Comment: I down voted your solution by mistake. I was just under the impression that everyone says it's not doable. This is why I added that reflection-based solution. Good solution dude!

Comment: This breaks the very basic rule "do not call virtual methods in constructor" :)

Answer (score 17):

The only solution I can think of is to return the value from the `Init()` method that the `readonly` field needs to be assigned:

```
public class Class
{
    private readonly int readonlyField;

    public Class()
    {
        readonlyField = Init();
    }

    private int Init()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was sure I saw this done.. My brain must be playing tricks on me. Thanks all

Comment: @BenAnderson, I know what you mean - I spent hours a few days ago trawling the 'net as I was sure that I'd read somewhere that SMB2 allows a file-copy from one remote server to another to not be routed via the client machine making the request. Hours lost and I could find no evidence, though I was *adamant* I'd read that it was possible! :S

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using an Initialize method, how about inheriting a basic constructor through all your other constructors. 
i.e.

```
public class MyClass
{
    readonly int field1;
    readonly double field2;
    public MyClass(int field1, double field2)
    {
        //put whatever initialization logic you need here...
        field1 = 10;
        field2 = 30.2;
    }
    public MyClass(int field1, double field2p1, double field2p2)
        : this(field1, (field2p1 + field2p2))
    {
        //put anything extra in here
    }
}
```

This may be a little late to reach the original person in need, but it seems like this will cleanly solve the problem... Without the need to use any sort of nasty reflection or out parameters.

Comment: This is definitely a smarter way to share code between constructors.

Answer (score 7):

Jared is right; this is not possible. The workarounds I can think of are:

1. Initialize the field in the declaration.
2. Initialize the field in the constructor (Manually inline your `Init` method).
3. Assign the field to a value returned by a method, e.g.: `_myField = GetInitialMyFieldValue();`
4. Pass the field to the `Init` method, with the `out` modifier. This may be useful if you have many fields to initialize, which are dependent on constructor parameters. E.g.

---

```
 private readonly int _x;
 private readonly string _y;

 private void Init(int someConstructorParam, out int x, out string y){ .. }

 public Class(int someConstructorParam)
 {
     Init(someConstructorParam, out _x, out _y);
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

This cannot be done.  Fields which are tagged with `readonly` can only be set from the constructor

Comment: Not that it's completely wrong, but this answer really does pale in comparison to the other answers around here. A simple "cannot be done" one sentence answer leaves a lot to be desired. Maybe this was one of the first answers though?

Answer (score 4):

What i ended up doing in current tech (C# 7.x) is use the value tuple system:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly int x;
    private readonly int y;
    private readonly int z;

    public MyClass(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
        (y, z) = InitYandZ();
    }

    private (int, int) InitYandZ()
    {
        return (5, 10);
    }
}
```

Not the cleanest either, But seems cleaner to me.

Answer (score 1):

C# compiler only allows you to set readonly fields if you're initializing them inline:

```
private readonly int readonlyField = 1;
```

or from the constructor:

```
public Class()
{
    readonlyField = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an initialized property with a getter only (as of C# 6.0)?

```
    private int MyProperty { get; } = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but what about using a class as a return value instead of using out params if there is a need to initialize multiple fields, are there any drawacks? Imho this is more convenient and more readable than using nested constructors.

```
public class MyInitClass
{
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    private readonly int readonlyField1;
    private readonly int readonlyField2;

    public Class()
    {
        var init = Init();
        readonlyField1 = init.Field1;
        readonlyField2 = init.Field2;
    }

    private MyInitClass Init()
    {
        return new MyInitClass() { Field1 = 1, Field2 = 2 };
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it works if use Reflection. Actually this works for me:

```
    public class Class
        {
            private readonly int readonlyField;
        public int MyField()
        {
             return readonlyField;
        }
        public Class()
        {
            readonlyField = 9;
        }
    }
```

and

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Class classObj = new Class();
            Console.WriteLine(classObj.MyField());//9

            Misc.SetVariableyByName(classObj, "readonlyField", 20);//20
            Console.WriteLine(classObj.MyField());
         }
```

this is SetVariableByName():

```
public static b

ool SetVariableyByName(object obj, string var_name, object value)
            {
                FieldInfo info = obj.GetType().GetField(var_name, BindingFlags.NonPublic| BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (info == null)
                return false;
            /* ELSE */
            info.SetValue(obj, value);
            return true;          
        }
```

the only thing is that readonlyField is public not private. I know that you can edit a private field, but am not sure why its not working for me!

Comment: Just because you *can* do it this way doesn't mean that you *should*... and of course in many situations you won't have permission to do this.

Comment: I don't think this is what reflection was meant for. Unnecessary performance hit...

Comment: Well guys, true! But if you weren't given the choice, and have to deal with such a situation, you have to do something.. Reflection is not the best technique to use, but it solves problems.

Comment: Why would anyone do this? Seems to violate any class invariants that could have been in place. A very bad idea.

Comment: This is one of the kinds of monster solution that makes some old time c programmers think OOP is evil...lol