# Simplification of Constructors Assigning to readonly Fields

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I have the following class:

```
public class MyCollection<T1, T2> : AnotherCollection<T1>
{
    private readonly ICollection<T2> BaseCollection;

    public MyCollection(IEnumerable<T1> collection, ICollection<T2> baseCollection) : base(collection)
    {
        BaseCollection = baseCollection;
    }

    public MyCollection(List<T1> collection, ICollection<T2> baseCollection) : base(collection)
    {
        BaseCollection = baseCollection;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to simplify this code such that `BaseCollection = baseCollection;` is only written once?

Comment: Maybe look into this article if you need to choose if you need IEnumerable vs ICollection vs IList. https://medium.com/developers-arena/ienumerable-vs-icollection-vs-ilist-vs-iqueryable-in-c-2101351453db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this here:

[How do I set a readonly field in an initialize method that gets called from the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728447/how-do-i-set-a-readonly-field-in-an-initialize-method-that-gets-called-from-the)

Implemented in my example as:

```
public class MyCollection<T1, T2> : AnotherCollection<T1>
{
    private readonly ICollection<T2> BaseCollection;

    public MyCollection(IEnumerable<T1> collection, ICollection<T2> baseCollection) : base(collection)
    {
        Init(baseCollection, out BaseCollection);
    }

    public MyCollection(List<T1> collection, ICollection<T2> baseCollection) : base(collection)
    {
        Init(baseCollection, out BaseCollection);
    }
    
    private void Init(ICollection<T2> baseCollection, out ICollection<T2> baseCollectionAssigment)
    {
        baseCollectionAssigment = baseCollection;
    }
}
```

One thing I like about this is being able to have a single `Init` method, in which I could have further code that is common to both constructors. If I were to add another similar constructor, I would just have one line of code to write for it.

Answer (score 3):

IEnumerable can support both a List and Collection. So you don't need both constructors. With a single constructor like this you can initialize a List and IEnumerable

```
public class MyCollection<T1, T2> : AnotherClass<T1>
{
    private readonly ICollection<T2> BaseCollection;

    public MyCollection(IEnumerable<T1> collection, ICollection<T2> baseCollection) : base(collection)
    {
        BaseCollection = baseCollection;
    }
}
```

**Your initial solution is perfectly acceptable, especially if there are different implementations based on type.**

If there's a different implementation on the base class for IEnumerable and List, then check something like this, **but not recommended**

**REMEMBER, OVER OPTIMIZATION IS THE ROOT OF ALL EVIL**

```
public class AnotherClass<T1>
{
    public AnotherClass(IEnumerable<T1> collection)
    {
        var type = collection.GetType();

        if (type == typeof(IEnumerable<T1>))
        {
            //Do the implementation Detail for IEnumerable
        }
        else if (type == typeof(List<T1>))
        {
            //Do the implementation Detail for List    
        }
        else if (type == typeof(Collection<T1>))
        {
            //Do the implementation Detail for ICollection
        }
        else
        {
            //Do the implementation Detail for Default
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While it may work in this case, the problem I see here is that the base constructor for passing in `List<T1>` is not called, which may have a different implementation (e.g., in classes other than `ObservableCollection`). In general, is there a way this could be made to call both base constructors, while still writing the `BaseCollection` assignment only once?

Comment: Posted an updated in the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can make the second constructor call the first constructor:

```
public MyCollection(IEnumerable<T1> collection, ICollection<T2> baseCollection) : base(collection)
{
    BaseCollection = baseCollection;
}

public MyCollection(List<T1> collection, ICollection<T2> baseCollection) 
    : this((IEnumerable<T1>)collection, baseCollection)
{
    // you can do additional initialisation for the List<T1> case here
}
```

Note that it is necessary to convert `collection` to `IEnumerable<T1>`, so that the call does not resolve to the same constructor again, which is invalid. Other than a cast, you can also use `as IEnumerable<T1>` or `AsEnumerable()`.

This could be useful if you want some extra stuff to be done when the caller passes in a list, rather than an `IEnumerable<T>`. If there's nothing additional that you want to do, you don't actually need two constructors here. `List<T1>` implements `IEnumerable<T1>`, so you just need the `IEnumerable<T1>` one.

---

If the two `base(collection)` calls are actually calling different constructors of the base class (with different implementations), then there are not many choices. All I can think of is to use `dynamic` and have only one constructor like this:

```
public MyCollection(IEnumerable<T1> collection, ICollection<T2> baseCollection) : base((dynamic)collection)
{
    BaseCollection = baseCollection;
}
```

This would make it choose which constructor to call based on the runtime type of the collection passed in. This means that even if you have a `List<T1>`, you can't choose to call the `IEnumerable<T1>` base constructor by casting it to `IEnumerable<T1>` like before. You must create a new `IEnumerable`, that is not a `List`.

Comment: While it may work in this case, the problem I see here is that neither is calling the base constructor for passing in `List<T1>`, which may have a different implementation (e.g., in classes other than `ObservableCollection`). In general, is there a way this could be made to call both base constructors, while still writing the `BaseCollection` assignment only once?

Comment: @ChrisMack Ah I see what you are *actually* asking now. Well, the only solution I can think of is to use Zee's answer, but change the first constructor's delegation to `: base((dynamic)collection)`. This still has some caveats though - for example, you can't explicitly choose to call the `IEnumerable` base constructor by casting anymore.

Comment: @ChrisMack I would suggest that you edit your question to clarify that *this* is what you want to do.